# Unexpected output while splitting and parsing a string into int (Java)

Tags: java

```
public static void main (String args[]) {

  Scanner io = new Scanner(System.in);
  int a = io.nextInt();
  io.nextLine();
  for(int i = 0; i < a; i++ ) {  
     String input = io.nextLine();
     String[] splitArr = input.split("\\s+");
     int p[] = new int[input.length()];
     int q = 0;
     for (String par : splitArr) {
       System.out.println(par);
       p[q++] = Integer.parseInt(par);
       System.out.println(p);
     }
     Sort(p);   
  }
}
```

> The input: 2 121213
>
> Output: 121213 [I@1f96302

The last line shows the array stored in p[]. That is incorrect. Help someone!

Comment: Do you mean to print System.out.println(p[q])?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your print line is incorrect, your print line should be:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p));
```

You also increment q in a wrong way, your increment code should be like:

```
   p[q] = Integer.parseInt(par);
   q++;
   System.out.println(p);
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. :)

Comment: But after the input: 2 121332, The output is coming out to be 121332 00000

Comment: I updated the answer and it will fix your 00000 output.